# Node.js - SendGrid : Doesn't send to my array recipients (only in production mode)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

***My env :***

```
"next": "^12.0.8",
"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.6.1"
```

***My code - API:***

```
import sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';

sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export default async function sendEmailDestinataire(req, res) {
  const msg = {
    to: req.body.email,
    from: {
      email: 'contact@aaaaaaa.fr',
      name: 'From my name',
    },
    templateId: 'd-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    dynamic_template_data: {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      message: req.body.message,
      file: req.body.file,
    },
  };
  console.log('====================================');
  console.log('api msg', msg.to);
  console.log('====================================');
  try {
    await sendgrid.sendMultiple(msg);
    res.json({ message: `Email has been sent` });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending email' });
  }
}
```

***My code  - FRONT***

```
let listEmails = '';
if (getUserMail.edges && getUserMail?.edges[0]?.node?.email === email) {
  const tmpListEmails = getUserMail.edges[0]?.node?.listeEmails?.emails;
  listEmails = tmpListEmails.replace(' ', '').split(',');
}

const res2 = await fetch('/api/sendgridDestinataire', {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: listEmails.length > 0 ? listEmails : email,
    name: name,
    file: allUrls,
    message: message,
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: 'POST',
});
await res.json();
```

***My problem :***

In my development environment everything works fine.
But when I'm in production, the email is sent to the email state. And no, to those from my array.
The email variable transmitted to the API sends me back the object...

Thank you in advance for your help.

And sorry for my English

Bruce

Comment: In production, do you have your `SENDGRID_API_KEY` set correctly? Is there an error when you try to send in production?

Comment: Hi, yes my envs is correctly.
Emails sending but only an recipients and not array recipients...